# bound width of a single lstlisting to one column inside a two column IEEE template

Tags: listings, two-column, ieeetran, width, code

I use `IEEE` double column template and inside it I add a `C++` code. I expect the code to be bounded within a single column however it infringes to the next column. How to fix this code?

I would avoid any solution affecting all `lstlisting` inside the latex file. I prefer to fix the code inline.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\columnwidth,language=C++]
out= in + dnx1 + dnx2 + dnx3 + dnx4 + dnx5 + dnx6 + dnx7 + dnx8 + dnx9 + dnx10;
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: latex lstlisting double column]

Comment: `breaklines=true,`

Comment: @HarishKumar fantastic. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `breaklines=true` as the option. Further you may define

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
```

to add some difference.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\columnwidth,breaklines=true,language=C++]
out= in + dnx1 + dnx2 + dnx3 + dnx4 + dnx5 + dnx6 + dnx7 + dnx8 + dnx9 + dnx10;
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]